# (jqGrid) Error when finding clicked row number

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

```
function drawTable(url){
        $('#reportList').jqGrid('GridUnload');

        $('#reportList').jqGrid({
            url: url,
            mtype: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',


            colNames:['num','section1','section_detail','product','product_description','status','rate','start_date','end_date','issue','in_charge','write_date','view'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'num', index:'num', hidden:true},
                {name:'section1', index:'section1',  width:60},
                {name:'section2', index:'section2'},
                {name:'product', index:'product', width:90},
                {name:'product_description', index:'product_description'},
                {name:'status', index:'status', width:50},
                {name:'rate', index:'rate', width:50},
                {name:'start_date', width:90, index:'start_date'},
                {name:'completion_date', width:90, index:'completion_date'},
                {name:'issues', index:'issues'},
                {name:'in_charge', index:'in_charge', width:80},

                {name:'writedate', index:'writedate',width:90},
                {name:'rewrite', index:'rewrite', width:60, formatter: function addButton(cellvalue, options, rowobject){


                return "<input class='btnEdit' type='button' value='view' onClick='editReport.call(this)'/>" 

                }}
            ],

            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'section1',
            sortorder: 'DESC',
            multiselect: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            rowNum:50,
            loadonce: true,
            multiselect:true,
            gridComplete: function(){


            }

        });

    }

    function editReport(){

        //get row number
        var clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");

        var ids = jQuery('#reportList').jqGrid('getDataIDs');

        // get row object with row num
        var rowId=ids[clickedRow-1];
        var rowData = jQuery('#reportList').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);

        getReportInfo(rowData.num)
  }
```

Hi, I'm making simple report program with Spring framework. 
To show all the reports registered, I applied jqGrid(It's thirteen-column table) for better user interface. all columns except 'num' and 'view' show the details of a report. column 'num' is hidden information to retrieve all the other information from database. the rightmost column ('view') is a button to view the detail of the report in child window.
In function 'editReport', I get 'num' of the report by finding the clicked row number.

I looked fine. However, when I set 15 row per page and changed to page 2, the variable of 'clickedRow' generate wrong number. When clicking first row of page 2, I expect 1, but it returns 16.. So, It can't get 'num' from clicked row and generate an error..

Comment: The code of `editReport` is incorrect. The value `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` is **not the row index**. It's the **rowid** by definition. You don't need to use `getDataIDs` at all. Instead of that you can use `var rowId = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");` and then uses the value as the option in `getRowData` or any in other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of `editReport` is incorrect. The value `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` is **not the row index**. It's the **rowid** by definition. You don't need to use `getDataIDs` at all. Instead of that you can use `var rowId = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");` and then uses the value as the option in `getRowData` or any in other methods.

Additionally, if `num` column contains **unique** value (the values are different in all rows) then you can add `key: true` property in the column definition of the `num` column in `colModel`. It will inform jqGrid to use the values from the column as the rowid (the value of `id` attribute for `<tr>` elements). One more way will be to add `jsonReader: { id: "num" }`, but to be sure that the way works you should include an example of JSON response from `url` (at least one row or JSON data). Moreover, it's important to know which *version* of jqGrid you use and from which *fork* of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: Thanks!!! This is what I've been looking for. I added 'key:true' to 'num' column and everything is working fine!